# Почему андроид приложение не запускается на моем устройстве через USB кабель?

Tags: android

Пытаюсь протестировать свое приложение на смартфоне, который подключен через USB - выдает такую ошибку:

```
Installation failed due to: ''pm install-create -r -t -S 3366360' returns error 'UNSUPPORTED''
```

Смартфон - xiaomi redmi note 4
Как исправить?

Comment: Ошибка говорит сама за себя.

Comment: В случае телефонов с MIUI помогает отключение `MIUI optimization` и ребут.

Comment: помогло отключение MIUI optimization. Спасибо)